# Regex to detect text inside <>

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match if string that can be multiple lines contains any tags surrounded with < > . My regex knowledge is quite limited, so far I got to

```
[\s,\S]*<\/?[A-Za-z][^>]*(?!>)[\s,\S]*
```

What I want it to do is detect opening < ,
that can be followed by 1 or more characters(letters) and this
cannot be followed by closing > .

I want all the text to be evaluated as match thus [\s,\S] on both sides.

So basically it should match only if no tag is detected.

With above this works: `hello<p>`      (not match)
But this not: `hello <pp>`     (will match and should not)

Anyone who can help here?

EDIT: Let's forget about html, I would like to have regex that matches on string if it does not contain any text wrapped in <>. I can't understand how answer posted in comment answers that. I do not want to parse anything..

Example string:   `hello there`  = match
Another: `hello <there>` = NO MATCH.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Liam I am not sure I understand this.. Link you posted is about parsing, I want to match string unless it contains any text wrapped in <>.

Comment: If you just want to detect that, that'd be as simple as [`/<\w+>/`](https://regexr.com/4157k). That would tell you if it contained `<there>` if you wanted to not match this then just negate the result

Comment: @Liam Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<[^>]+>
```

Then negate the result.